# Using stored array values read from a file C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file in which I am getting data (per line) and loading it into an array. I'm wondering if it's possible to use the array (1 per line) to name the buttons (10+ buttons) I have.
My goal is: Form 1 loads with multiple buttons on screen, form 2 will have data on it which changes the button text on form 1. I save a text file of all button text on form 1. When I reload the form, I'm wanting it to read from the text file with the saved changes and load those button names to it.

I have it saving the button text + loading the text file to an array, but how do I use the values from the array to change the buttons text for each button.

At the moment, it's only changing 1 button text to the whole array list I created.

```
string[] lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\CSharp\important.txt");

foreach (var item1 in lines1)
        {
            b1112.Text = item1;
            MessageBox.Show(item1);
        }
```

Comment: Absolutely yes.  I just completed a project where is did that using excel vba. The controls on the worksheet were easy.  The controls in a form could not be added by a vba script.  I even changed the size and location.In c# the work is pretty much the same.  It is probably better to add the controls instead of renaming.  With renaming you need to have the old name and new name in the text file.  Then find the control by the old name which is slow and takes time.

Comment: Hi, sorry should have clarified. Buttons are already added on the form page. I just need to change the button text. I can change the text through code but I want to change multiple buttons text through the array list

Comment: How did you plan to map a Button Name with its saved Text? Did you store a reference: `[Button Name]`:`[Text]` or `[Tag Value]`:`[Text]` or `[Button TabIndex]`:`[Text]` or something else? If so, use a Form's Controls collection to identify a Button and set its Text to the saved value. Using a Button's Name as mapped reference makes it easier.